# Java. Отправляю текстовые сообщения с клиента на сервер. Первые 5 переменных отправляются, остальные игнорируются

Tags: java, сокет

Написал приложение клиент и сервер. Клиент отправляет только текстовые сообщения на сервер. Оба приложения для компа. Проблема в том, что клиент отправляет только 5 сообщений, а остальные просто игнорирует. Сразу говорю, что я не профессиональный программист, поэтому прошу объяснить по проще, в чем может быть дело!) Клиент:

```
public class LaptopServer {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "myServerApp";

// ip адрес сервера, который принимает соединения
private String mServerName = "192.168.1.88";
// номер порта, на который сервер принимает соединения
private int mServerPort = 8520;
// сокет, через которий приложения общается с сервером
private Socket mSocket = null;

public LaptopServer() {}

// Открытие нового соединения. Если сокет уже открыт, то он закрывается.
//@throws Exception
//      Если не удалось открыть сокет
public void openConnection() throws Exception {

// Освобождаем ресурсы
closeConnection();

try {
    //Создаем новый сокет. Указываем на каком компютере и порту запущен наш процесс,
    //который будет принамать наше соединение.
    mSocket = new Socket(mServerName,mServerPort);

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Exception("Невозможно создать сокет: "+e.getMessage());
}
}

//Метод для закрытия сокета, по которому мы общались.
public void closeConnection(){

//Проверяем сокет. Если он не зарыт, то закрываем его и освобдождаем соединение.
if (mSocket != null && !mSocket.isClosed()) {

    try {
        mSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Невозможно закрыть сокет: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        mSocket = null;
    }

}
mSocket = null;
}

//Метод для отправки данных по сокету.
//@param data
//       Данные, которые будут отправлены
//@throws Exception
//       Если невозможно отправить данные
public void sendData(byte[] data) throws Exception {

/* Проверяем сокет. Если он не создан или закрыт, то выдаем исключение */
if (mSocket == null || mSocket.isClosed()) {
    throw new Exception("Невозможно отправить данные. Сокет не создан или закрыт");
}

/* Отправка данных */
try {
    mSocket.getOutputStream().write(data);
    mSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Exception("Невозможно отправить данные: "+e.getMessage());
}
}

//переопределить метод finalize() и освободить ресурс
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
super.finalize();
closeConnection();
}
}
```

Кнопка "Отправить":

```
sendPlannedButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //выключаем кнопку
        sendPlannedButton.setEnabled(false);
        //создаем объект для работы с сервером
        mServer = new LaptopServer();

        serverPass = "какой то пароль";
        sendPurchase = labelPurchase.getText();
        sendPurchase = sendPurchase.getBytes();
        Date date = new Date();
        sendDate = formatDate.format(date);
        sendName = logInName;
        sendEmail = logInEmail;
        sendNomenclature = new ArrayList<String>();
        sendNomenclature = selectNomenclaturePlanned;
        sendItem = new ArrayList<String>();
        sendItem = selectItemPlanned;

        if (mServer == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Сервер не создан");
        }

        //Открываем соединение. Открытие должно происходить в отдельном потоке
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    mServer.openConnection();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    //отправляем на сервер данные
                    mServer.sendData(serverPass.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    mServer.sendData(sendPurchase.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    mServer.sendData(sendDate.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    mServer.sendData(sendName.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    mServer.sendData(sendEmail.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(200);

                    for (int i=0; i<sendNomenclature.size(); i++){
                        mServer.sendData(sendNomenclature.get(i).getBytes());
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                        mServer.sendData(sendItem.get(i).getBytes());
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Произошла ошибка при отправке");
                    mServer = null;
                }
                //Закрываем соединение
                mServer.closeConnection();
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Сервер:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

//Реалезация шаблона Singleton
//{@link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern}

private static volatile Server instane = null;

//Порт, на который сервер принимает соеденения
private final int SERVER_PORT = 8520;
//Сокет, который обрабатывает соединения на сервере
private static ServerSocket serverSoket = null;

private Server() {
}

static Server getServer() {

if (instane == null) {
    synchronized (Server.class) {
        if (instane == null) {
            instane = new Server();
        }
    }
}
return instane;
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
    //Создаем серверный сокет, которые принимает соединения
    serverSoket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

    //старт приема соединений на сервер
    while(true) {
        ConnectionWorker worker = null;
        try {
            //ждем нового соединения
            worker = new ConnectionWorker(serverSoket.accept());

            //создается новый поток, в котором обрабатывается соединение
            Thread t = new Thread(worker);
            t.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MyFrame.journal = "<br>Connection error: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    MyFrame.journal = "<br>I can not start the server on the port "+SERVER_PORT+":"+e.getMessage();
}finally {
    //Закрываем соединение
    if (serverSoket != null) {
        try {
            serverSoket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            MyFrame.journal = "<br>"+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Сервер, приём сообщения:

```
public class ConnectionWorker implements Runnable{

//сокет, через который происходит обмен данными с клиентом
private Socket clientSocket = null;
//входной поток, через который получаем данные с сокета
private InputStream inputStream = null;


private String pass="какой то пароль";
private String name;
private String purchase;
private String date;
private String textNomenclature;
private String textAddress;
private String textRegNum;
private String textComment;
private ArrayList<String> nomenclature = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> metr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> regNum = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> comment = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> excelNomenclature;

private int num=0;
private int numUrgent=0;
private Path path;
private String textPath = "какой то путь";
private String textDatePath = "";



ConnectionWorker(Socket socket) {
clientSocket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
//получаем входной поток
try {
    inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    MyFrame.journal = "<br>Do not get the input stream";
}

//создаем буфер для данных
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

while (true) {
    try {
        //получаем очередную порцию данных
        //в переменной count хранится реальное количество байт, которое получили
        int count = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        //проверяем, какое количество байт к нам прийшло
        if (count > 0) {

            if (num==0){
                if (!(new String(buffer,0,count).equals(pass))){
                    MyFrame.journal = "<br>Unauthorized connection<br>close socket";
                    MyFrame.journalLabel += MyFrame.journal;
                    MyFrame.journalLabelUpdate();
                    MyFrame.journalUpdate();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    num=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    MyFrame.journal = "<br>Password confirmed";
                    MyFrame.journalLabel += MyFrame.journal;
                    MyFrame.journalLabelUpdate();
                    MyFrame.journalUpdate();
                    num++;
                }
            }
            else if (num==1){
                purchase = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                purchase = new String(purchase.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                num++;
                MyFrame.journal = "<br> Purchase: "+purchase;
                MyFrame.journalLabel += MyFrame.journal;
                MyFrame.journalLabelUpdate();
                MyFrame.journalUpdate();
            }
            else if (num==2){
                date = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                date = new String(date.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                String testDate = date.substring(8);
                int testDateNum = Integer.parseInt(testDate);
                if (testDateNum>19){
                    testDate = date.substring(5,7);
                    testDateNum = Integer.parseInt(testDate)+1;
                    textDatePath = new String(buffer, 0, 5);
                    textDatePath += Integer.toString(testDateNum);
                }else{
                    textDatePath = new String(buffer, 0, 7);
                }
                num++;
                MyFrame.journal = "<br> Date: "+date + "<br> Direct: " + textDatePath;
            }
            else if (num==3){
                name = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                name = new String(name.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                num++;
                MyFrame.journal = "<br> Sender: "+name;
            }
            else if (num==4){
                email = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                email = new String(email.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                num++;
                MyFrame.journal = "<br> Sender Email: "+ email;
            }
            else if (num>4 && purchase.equals("Плановая закупка")){
                if (!(num%2==0)){
                    textNomenclature = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    textNomenclature = new String(textNomenclature.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    nomenclature.add(textNomenclature);

                    MyFrame.journal = "<br> Num: "+ num;
                    num++;
                } else{
                    items.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(buffer, 0, count)));
                    num++;
                }
            }
            else if (num>4 && purchase.equals("Срочная закупка")){
                if (numUrgent==0 || numUrgent%6==0){
                    textNomenclature = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    textNomenclature = new String(textNomenclature.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    nomenclature.add(textNomenclature);
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
                else if (numUrgent==1 || (numUrgent-1)%6==0){
                    metr.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(buffer, 0, count)));
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
                else if (numUrgent==2 || (numUrgent-2)%6==0){
                    items.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(buffer, 0, count)));
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
                else if (numUrgent==3 || (numUrgent-3)%6==0){
                    textAddress = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    textAddress = new String(textAddress.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    address.add(textAddress);
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
                else if (numUrgent==4 || (numUrgent-4)%6==0){
                    textRegNum = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    textRegNum = new String(textRegNum.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    regNum.add(textRegNum);
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
                else if (numUrgent==5 || (numUrgent-5)%6==0){
                    textComment = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                    textComment = new String(textComment.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    comment.add(textComment);
                    numUrgent++;
                    num++;
                }
            }
        }else
            //если мы получили -1, значит прервался наш поток с данными
            if (count == -1 ) {
                MyFrame.journal = "<br>close socket";
                clientSocket.close();
                break;
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        MyFrame.journal = "<br>"+e.getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Вся магия ситуации заключается в том, что есть написанный клиент под Android, в котором отправка реализована один в один так же, и там всё работает отлично, а когда пишу клиент для компа, отправляет только первые 5 сообщений, т.е. вот это отправляется: serverPass, sendPurchase, sendDate, sendName, sendEmail

А цикл for срабатывает, но почему то не отправляется, при этом ошибок клиент не выдаёт. Даже если я вытащу переменные из цикла for и буду отправлять только первый элемент ArrayList, они всё равно не отправляются(
1. Почему так происходит, может быть кто посоветует какую статью? (желательно на русском языке).
2. Как сделать так, что бы клиент отсылал неограниченное ко-во текстовых сообщений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, оказалось, что цикл While(true){}в серверной части класса(ConnectionWorker) слишком большой и в какой то момент он перестаёт записывать. Решил отправлять не по одной переменной, а создавать объект на стороне клиента и отправлять этот объект разом. Так работает и записывает)

Comment: вместо if используйте case!!! 
Ваш if глаза режит!!!